# Is there a justification for having the pagination buttons at the top and at the bottom of data tables?

Tags: data-tables, pagination

I was wondering, if there is an appropriate justification for having the pagination buttons at the top and at the bottom of data tables? I remember observing this in the Salesforce app a while back, and I personally, have found a need for it once or twice. Now, I want to implement it in one of my designs but I would feel better if I had a real world use case to back it up.

Thanks in advance for any advice you may have for me.

Comment: Probably because the convention principle, books usually have their pages numeration on the bottom right corner and sometimes on the top right corner.

Comment: Makes sense, Nick, Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe its more useful at the bottom as users will decide to go to the next page when they didn't find what they were looking for.

But i've also observed (in e-commerce user tests) users wanting to go the next screen right away. This is when they assume what they are looking for isn't in the current screen based on what they seen on the 1st few rows. This could happen when there's too many similar products in a catalog. In this case having a pagination on top can be quite useful.

Comment: That's a great use case! Thanks Ameen.